# K2 extra fields access in BT Content slider

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I'm trying to access the contents of a K2 extra field inside the BT content slider plugin. If I do

```
print_r($row->extra_fields);
```

I get

```
[{"id":"16","value":"http:\/\/www.youblisher.com\/p\/611670-Test-Intro-to-R\/"}]
```

I need to access the value, but I've tried everything I could think of with no luck.

Tests I've done (also tried print_r for everything just in case):

```
echo $row->extra_fields[0]
echo $row->extra_fields[0]->value
echo $row->extra_fields->value
echo $row->extra_fields["value"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decode your string into a json object first before trying to access value.

```
<?php
$json = json_decode('[{"id":"16","value":"http:\/\/www.youblisher.com\/p\/611670-Test-   Intro-to-R\/"}]');
print_r($json[0]->value);
?>
```

Comment: That was quick and perfectly accurate :-) Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got it working the way I wanted it to.

I wanted to replace intro / full text with an extrafield that I called 'Accroche' . This extrafield has an ID of 132 (useful to know the ID that will be used in code below).

We will be editing 2 files :

/modules/mod_bt_contentslider/classes/content.php
and
/modules/mod_bt_contentslider/classes/k2.php

First thing to do is get the extrafield info from database :

in /modules/mod_bt_contentslider/classes/content.php (around line 77) I added  [b]a.extra_fields,[/b] as follows

```
 $model->setState('list.select', 'a.urls, a.images, a.fulltext, a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.introtext, a.extra_fields, a.state, a.catid, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias,' . ' a.modified, a.modified_by,a.publish_up, a.publish_down, a.attribs, a.metadata, a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.access,' . ' a.hits, a.featured,' . ' LENGTH(a.fulltext) AS readmore');
```

Save file & close

Now lets get to /modules/mod_bt_contentslider/classes/k2.php (around line 234),

Replace this original code

```
// cut introtext
        if ($limitDescriptionBy == 'word') {

            $item->description = self::substrword($item->introtext, $maxDesciption, $replacer, $isStrips, $stringtags);

            $item->description = self::substring($item->introtext, $maxDesciption, $replacer, $isStrips, $stringtags);

        }
        $item->categoryLink = urldecode(JRoute::_(K2HelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->catid . ':' . urlencode($item->categoryalias))));

// get author name & link
```

With this code that I've commented to make things understandable for noobs like me ;)

```
        // REPLACE intro/full text With extra-field info
        $extras = json_decode($item->extra_fields); // JSON Array we'll call extras (note final 's' : not to confuse with below variable)
        foreach ($extras as $key=>$extraField): //Get values from array
            if($extraField->value != ''):  //If not empty
                    if($extraField->id == '132'): // This is ID value for extrafield I want to show --- Search your K2 extrafield's id in Joomla backoffice ->K2 ->extrafields ---
                        if($extraField->value != ''): // If there's content in the extrafield of that ID 
                            $extra = $extraField->value; //Give $extra that value so we can hand it down below
                        endif; 
                    endif; 
            endif; 
        endforeach; 

        // cut introtext
        if ($limitDescriptionBy == 'word') {

           // $item->description = self::substrword($item->introtext, $maxDesciption, $replacer, $isStrips, $stringtags);
            $item->description = self::substrword($extra, $maxDesciption, $replacer, $isStrips, $stringtags);
        } else {

           // $item->description = self::substring($item->introtext, $maxDesciption, $replacer, $isStrips, $stringtags);
             $item->description = self::substring($extra, $maxDesciption, $replacer, $isStrips, $stringtags) ;

        }
        $item->categoryLink = urldecode(JRoute::_(K2HelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->catid . ':' . urlencode($item->categoryalias))));

        // get author name & link
```

As you can see, I've commented out the intro texts as I don't want them. You can modify that if you want both introtext AND extrafield.

I'd have never figured this out without the JSON tip given above. Thanx to all :)

Hope this helps.

Cheers !